# Removed Google account keeps coming back

Tags: macos, big-sur, gmail

I'm trying to remove an old Google account from macOS.  I remove it from `Internet Accounts` in System Preferences and then confirm I want to remove it from all computers using iCloud Keychain.  Then after a few minutes it comes right back and I get a notification saying a new Google account has been added.

I'm running Big Sur 11.6.5 and I've already tried rebooting the computer.
[image]

Comment: Can you check if the account maybe was added through a profile, that's still installed?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that ALL your computers and devices (e.g. iPad, iPhone, Apple TV and even Apple Watch) are completely logged out of ALL Google services. Then remove Google from your Internet accounts, shutdown, wait 10 minutes and boot up/check that it's gone.

For that matter, you may also want to delete the account from your phone AND your other devices since your phone may check for mail on Google and prevent it from being deleted.

I don't know whether "ALT Elliott" and "fifteen" are computers, phones or what, but if any of them are using the Google login, they will cause it to be reinserted.

Another thing to try: Change the password on the account, then delete it on all your devices...that way they can't login again.

Good luck!

Comment: Related: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/icloud-keychain-issue-with-old-devices-appearing-for-shared-internet-accounts.2292186/ — I have this issue as well, can't get rid of these deleted accounts, they keep coming back. Driving me nuts.